# What's the difference between static-key and __builtin_expect?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I read the linux kernel document, and this file descript static-key:http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.1/Documentation/static-keys.txt

So, what's difference between static-key and __builtin_expect? They are all imply we can use them to implement **likyly()** and **unlikely()**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `__builtin_expect` introduces a true **test-and-branch** instruction in the code which needs to be evaluated by the CPU, while the instructions from the more likelier path-to-be-followed continue to be pre-fetched into the CPU pipeline.
- `static_key_*` introduces a `NOP` instruction that occupies sufficient space in the code that can be later patched during run-time to add a `jmp <label>`. This can be used to accommodate debugging prints with zero-impact on the regular working case i.e while the code is not being debugged.

From the [Linux kernel documentation for **`static-keys`**](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/static-keys.txt),

> gcc (v4.5) adds a new 'asm goto' statement that allows branching to a
>   label:
>   [gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2009-07/msg01556.html](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2009-07/msg01556.html)
>
> Using the 'asm goto', we can create branches that are either taken or
>   not taken by default, without the need to check memory. Then, at
>   run-time, we can patch the branch site to change the branch direction.
>
> For example, if we have a simple branch that is disabled by default:
>
> ```
> if (static_key_false(&key))
>         printk("I am the true branch\n");
> ```
>
> Thus, by default the 'printk' will not be emitted. And the code
>   generated will consist of a single atomic 'no-op' instruction (5 bytes
>   on x86), in the straight-line code path. When the branch is 'flipped',
>   we will patch the 'no-op' in the straight-line code-path with a 'jump'
>   instruction to the out-of-line true branch. Thus, changing branch
>   direction is expensive but branch selection is basically 'free'. That
>   is the basic tradeoff of this optimization.

This low-level patching mechanism is called 'jump label patching`, the basis of static-keys.

Comment: Do you know where is that patching done, or how do I instruct the kernel to do this patching? I dont see it in `static_key_false` or in `static_key_slow_inc` functions...

Comment: Consider a key that is initially `false`. `static_key_false(&key)` skips the **true path** and takes the **false path**. Now, invoking `static_key_slow_inc(key)` updates the value of the `key` from `0` to `1` i.e. the key is now `TRUE`. All subsequent  `static_key_false(&key)` would now take the **true branch**.